# Rails how can I pass collection to a partial view, that is rendered from *.js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I do this in my `update.js.erb` from the `RewardsController`:

```
$('div#rewards_list').html("<%=
  escape_javascript(render :partial    => 'shared/rewards',
                           :collection => @rewards,
                           :as => reward,
                           :locals => { :user => @user }
                   )
%>");
```

But the log says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `reward' for
  #<#<Class:0xbb395d8>:0xbb3774c>):
```

In my 'update' action method:

```
def update
  @user   = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @reward = @user.rewards.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reward.update_attributes(params[:reward])
      @rewards = @user.rewards

      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    else
      flash[:error] = "There is an error while updating the reward, please try again!"

      format.html { redirect_to @user }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:as` option should be given a symbol, not a variable (and especially not a variable that doesn't exist), perhaps you mean this:

```
$('div#rewards_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/rewards', :collection => @rewards, :as => :reward, :locals => {:user => @user}) %>");
```

I just changed `:as => reward` to `:as => :reward`. See the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables) guide for details.